# How do I fix Python/Flask throwing ModuleNotFound errors when referencing code I wrote?

Tags: python, flask, python-import, modulenotfounderror

I've been building out a backend in Flask for a few weeks now- I've been able to run the server locally & deploy it in the cloud without any problems. Today, my imports started not responding correctly & giving me ModuleNotFound errors. This is my file structure:

```
src
-server.py (Flask runs this file)
-X (directory)
--__init__.py
--X_functions.py
--X_utils.py

`server.py` contains `import X`, and X.__init__ contains:

`import X_functions`
`import X_utils`
```

When I go to run the server, I get an error messages stating `No module named X`. Any ideas what's going wrong here? This is the latest & toughest in a long slew of import errors I've been facing today, but it's not responding to any of my other tricks- any advice would be greatly appreciated!

I ran the server as normal, but got import errors that had never come up before.

Comment: Try using [relative imports](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/import.html#package-relative-imports) inside your packages. `from . import X_functions`